# Method overloading Typescript. Infer second argument type from the type of the first one

Tags: typescript

Im trying to implement method oveloading in Typescript.
I want to make more strict typechecking for the method invocation based on different arguments.
For example I want the type of the second argument infered by the value of the first one which is enum. I get an error though:

> 'props' is possibly 'undefined'.

for the following piece of code ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcAwhAHYxQSYFmVRwDeAUHHAPQdw4UFXocMaAAow6AEaYAljjj9UMYAC44AZWkBzcqkwAeNTEXAAfHAC88rTswjDxgHQBJBJmABKd8wC+LNomkCMEUcAAsRYAA3VQBRSOBKBwAlYAJgGHdVSIhpBABufwRA4JgwiOi4OISYBwARYDclABo4MGowAlUmOFzVcnQAWwlgRm9MuGzcgvYioJDwqNj4yha2iA6Afi6ehC24fqGRuDGsnIRmf3ZpZDhyi3NLKsT6xo8L9g+ePngDvsHhxiWNYdBxTS7Hfy+XwsUCQWBwBKDdRGJTvOAuNwWOAAIgxwGxTX8L3S0nImix2OJMFJmgJRIa6WAtQowApVKZLLp0Nh0HgiIGlWW8FY7HZbIZSjp7BSaXglmxMvSXL8yHQ5CE0goiAlwCcSgGIl6+3+Iy8rF8QA)):

```
export default class ControlsContr {
  // constructor(public state: Signal<State> = signal(State.Idle)) {}

  dispatch(ev: Event.Reset): void;
  dispatch(ev: Event.Delete, props: { id: number }): void;
  dispatch(ev: Event, props?: { id?: number }): void {
    if (ev === Event.Delete) {
      const num: number = props.id;
    }
  }
}

export enum State {
  Idle = "Idle",
  Deleting = "Deleting",
  DeleteDone = "DeleteDone",
}

export enum Event {
  Delete = "Delete",
  Reset = "Reset",
}

function deleteItem(id: number) {
}
```

I suppose my question is whether what Im trying to achieve is even possible and if possible how?

Answer (score 0):

Because the overload signatures have correlated parameters, you need to write an implementation signature that correlates the parameters in the same way. You can do that using a notation which represents the parameters as a [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) tuple of [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#unions) whose members are tuples which represent the same pairings found in the overload signatures. This will allow the compiler to correctly infer using the existing discriminant conditional. Here's an example to demonstrate:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwKIDcnwN4BQccAIsADbAzBwC8cARGZdQwDRFwBKwAzlXUY9+MdgQC+BAqEiw4AE2AAzAIbJy8AMbkVvXnADCERDCgRyvIyahxCxeQEteYFTE0ALABTAsALkw4JgB0wlQAlP5YEA7yANycjs6uHt5+AbhBzFTAbHBgZmC8-nhwMf4oqABGwDbiEXBRMfH2Ti5uXpzEQd0A2j65+RCFALr+fWnYGaEwuciIikoOiMDyAPzDcAA+cD2dxAgTgTCZFNkc+-uDhcWl8uVo1bXn+8OcYbZ7DkpwqXS09JNgllqO87BcDnsAPSQgB6qz2xCuvChsPhCLgmmMvHgFUESKCTTg0LgEAA1uiLtC4XtxAgLDQwRcfCjqeC8gVkZTUTTOJJJEA)

```ts
class ControlsContr {
  dispatch(ev: Event.Reset): void;
  dispatch(ev: Event.Delete, props: { id: number }): void;
  dispatch(
    ...[ev, props]: [ev: Event.Reset, undefined?] | [
      ev: Event.Delete,
      props: { id: number },
    ]
  ) {
    if (ev === Event.Delete) {
      ev
    //^? (parameter) ev: Event.Delete
      props
    //^? (parameter) props: { id: number }

      const num = props.id; // ok
          //^? const num: number
    } else {
      ev
    //^? (parameter) ev: Event.Reset
      props
    //^? (parameter) props: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Typescript's documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types):

> In addition to the general types string and number, **we can refer to specific strings and numbers in type positions**. [...] By combining literals into unions, you can express a much more useful concept - for example, **functions that only accept a certain set of known values**. [...] There’s one more kind of literal type: boolean literals.

Therefore, you can't make it using enums. However, you can use strings:

```js
export default class ControlsContr {
  dispatch(ev: "Reset"): void;
  dispatch(ev: "Delete", props: { id: number }): void;
  dispatch(ev: Event, props?: { id?: number }): void {}
}

export type Event = "Delete" | "Reset"

const controls = new ControlsContr()
controls.dispatch("Reset")
controls.dispatch("Delete", {id: 1})
// controls.dispatch("Reset", {id: 1}) fails
// controls.dispatch("Delete") fails
```

Or by [discriminating unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions):

```js
export default class ControlsContr {
  dispatch(ev: Event): void {
    if (ev.action == "Delete") {
      console.log(ev.id)
    }
  }
}

type ResetEvent = {action: "Reset"};
type DeleteEvent = {action: "Delete", id: number};
type Event = ResetEvent | DeleteEvent

const controls = new ControlsContr()
controls.dispatch({action: "Reset"})
controls.dispatch({action: "Delete", id: 1})
```